# JS: Динамические переменные и exports

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста -

Есть условный cf.js из которого я забираю имена необходимых мне элементов

```
        var a001 = ~ что то происходит
        var a002 = ~ что то происходит

        exports.exportname001 = a001;
        exports.exportname002 = a002;
```

И есть, допустим main.js, в котором я делаю require cf.js, и где-то в теле main - есть свой списочек нужных мне элементов из оного

```
var elements = ["exportname001", "exportname002"]
```

Дальше, мне нужно пройтись по каждому из списка, и выполнить стороннюю функцию, которая принимает мой элемент через cf.js и `true/false`

```
elements.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
cf.exportname001.some_api_function(true);
}
```

Только вместо exportname001, который я поставил для примера (*который офк отрабатывает*) - я должен вставлять соответственно текущий `item` (*или `elements[i]`, что по идее лучше - в этом же цикле мне предстоит обращаться и к `elements[i+1]`*) как имя переменной.

С любыми другими вариантами соответственно, кроме напечатанного - exports. просто не отрабатывает.

`item, elements[i]` - мимо. Новая переменная со значением `item` - нет.
Когда я понял что мне нужно создать имя переменной из значения - попробовал  `объект[]` и вызывать через него

```
var Obj = {};
var x = item;
alert(Obj[item]);
```

но тоже не вышло.
Мне кажется я не понимаю каких-то простых вещей, в силу не особо глубоких познаний.

Comment: Если честно ничего не понятно

Comment: `cf[item].some_api_function(true)`. Может какой-нибудь курс для начинающих пройти? Это же азы JS

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо!